# Panel regression / use of dummies as interaction terms

Tags: regression, interaction, panel-data

I am interested in using a fixed effects panel regression for my research question. Using fixed effects model instead of random effects is dictated by the Hausmann test results. In my sample, I have two types of funds. I would like to see if Type A fund shows different results than Type B. The way I distinguish them is through a dummy variable (with Type A fund having the value of 1 while Type B model having the value of 0). I would like to study differences between the Type A and Type B models in a panel regression set-up.

To simplify things, I would like to run the following:

```
Return (dependent variable) vs market return; market return(t)*dummy
```

My questions are:

1. Should the coefficients of `market return(t)* dummy` be significant, can I interpret this as Type A funds having significantly different returns from Type B funds' returns?
2. Should I also include the dummy variable as a separate and stand-alone variable in order to ensure that the panel regression set-up is complete? My current thinking is that it is not necessary.
3. Assuming for a moment that random effects were also suitable, what would this change in relation to the above set-up?

Comment: Market return is consistent across funds and it does not vary cross sectionally but varies over time

Answer (score 1):

From what you've written, I guess your model is the following
$$
return_{it} = \alpha_i+\beta_1\text{market return}_{it}+\beta_2\text{Type}_i+\beta_3\text{market return}_{it}\times\text{type} + \epsilon_{it}
$$
I suppose the answers are

1. Yes, conditional on non-confoundedness.  You need to be able to argue that you are controlling for everything time-varying (fixed effects), or absolutely everything (random effects)
2. In a RE specification, yes.  But RE specifications are rarely justified.  You need to be able to say that the individual effects $\alpha_i$ are completely unrelated to your independent variables.  In FE, the type dummy is colinear with the fixed effect, unless it varies in time.
3. See above

I should say that I don't know anything about your context.  Does "market return" vary across cross-sectional units $i$?